# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData ' on a null object reference

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I am getting the following error

I am using Android architecture components and tried to instantiate viewmodel and Observe data from LiveData. But im stuck here please help me solve this issue :

code showing issue:

```
notesView.getAllData.observe(this,notes->{
binding.notesRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
adapter=new notesAdapter(MainActivity.this,notes);
binding.notesRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
});
```

MainActivity.java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
 NotesView notesView;
 notesAdapter adapter;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.newNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,InsertNotes.class));
            }
        });
notesView.getAllData.observe(this,notes->{
binding.notesRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
adapter=new notesAdapter(MainActivity.this,notes);
binding.notesRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
});


    }
```

NotesEntity:

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "Notes_Db")
public class NotesEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name="notes_title")
    public String title;

    @ColumnInfo(name="notes_subtitle")
    public String subtitle;

    @ColumnInfo(name="notes")
    public String notes;


    @ColumnInfo(name="notes_date")
    public String date;

    @ColumnInfo(name="notes_priority")
    public String priority;



}
```

Notes Dao :

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.model.NotesEntity;

import java.util.List;

@androidx.room.Dao
public interface NotesDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Notes_Db")
    LiveData<List<NotesEntity>>getNotes();




    @Insert
    void insert(NotesEntity... notesEntities);


    @Query("Delete From Notes_Db Where id=:id")
    void delete(int id);


    @Update
    void update(NotesEntity notesEntity);


}
```

Repository class :

```
import android.app.Application;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.dao.NotesDao;
import com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.database.DbClass;
import com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.model.NotesEntity;

import java.util.List;

public class NotesRepo {

    public NotesDao notesDao;
    public LiveData<List<NotesEntity>>getallNotes;

    public NotesRepo(Application application) {
        DbClass db=DbClass.getDbInstance(application);
        notesDao=db.notesDao();
        getallNotes=notesDao.getNotes();
    }

    public void insertNotes(NotesEntity notes){
        notesDao.insert(notes);
    }
    public void deleteNotes(int id){
        notesDao.delete(id);
    }
    public void updateNotes(NotesEntity notes){
        notesDao.update(notes);
    }
}
```

Adapter for recyclerView:

```
public class notesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<notesAdapter.notesViewHolder> {
    MainActivity mainActivity;
     List<NotesEntity> notesEntities;
String TAG="NOTES_ADAPTER";
    public notesAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<NotesEntity> notesEntities) {
this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
this.notesEntities=notesEntities;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public notesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new notesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.notes_show,parent,false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull notesViewHolder holder, int position) {
            NotesEntity noteCol=notesEntities.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(noteCol.title);
            holder.subTitle.setText(noteCol.subtitle);
            holder.date.setText(noteCol.date);
            if(noteCol.priority=="1"){
                holder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.low_priority);
            }else if(noteCol.priority=="2"){
                holder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mid_priority);
            }else if(noteCol.priority=="3"){
                holder.priority.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.high_priority);
            }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notesEntities.size();
    }
    class notesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title,subTitle,date;
        View priority;
        public notesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesTitleShow);
            subTitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesSubTitle);
            date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesDateShow);
            priority=itemView.findViewById(R.id.showPrio);
        }
    }
}
```

Error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm, PID: 1748
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm/com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.viewModel.NotesView.getAllData' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.viewModel.NotesView.getAllData' on a null object reference
        at com.codeeraayush.notesapp_mvvm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your `viewmodel` before using it.

add this line in `onCreate` method (before line 36):

```
notesView = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotesView.class);
```